# Is there any way to do this with list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

This is the code I've written:

```
x=['U','D','D','D','U','D','U','U']
y=[]
for i in x:
    if i=='U':
        y.append(1)
    else:
        y.append(-1)
print(y)
```

Replacing U with 1 and D with -1.
Can we do the same using list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried something? What problem you have faced?

Comment: this is not a place for homework problems. Give information about what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: You should add code you have tried and explain where you have problems

Comment: I am new to python, I just wanted to know how to replace that code using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite easy.  You combine a list comprehension with a ternary expression.

```
y = [1 if i=='U' else -1 for i in x]
```